# Caching layers on the fly and seeding combination

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, generate-tiles

I have created a map in geoserver Im am using geoserver 2.5.1 with the intergrated geowebcache.

The map seems to be working fine and the seeding also seems to be working fine provided I don't use a bounding box for some strange reason.
But also want it to cache on the fly as well so I can seed the main sections of the map that would be used and have on the fly caching in the areas that arn't being used as much.

Am I mistaken in thinking that it saves those certain tiles like the seeding does or does it do it virtually or save in a temp tile folder and then goes away instantly tht person either closes the map program.

I have set everything that I could set but for some reason on the fly caching does not seem to work.

Am i missing something in the settings?
Or am misunder standing something with regards to it as in the geoserver documention states that it can combine both on the fly caching as well as seeding the layers.

Comment: The integrated "Tile layers" are seeded on the fly only if the client is making WMS requests which suit perfectly with the tile grid. That means in practice that the client is an OpenLayers/Leaflet application or WMS-C capable client like uDig. Request from normal WMS clients are passed on. I remember there was a problem with seeding with BBOX if Zoom Start level was not 0. How it was for you?

Comment: I am using openlayers to show the entire map with layers.
I usually put the zoom level at 1 but ocasionaly I move to it either 4 or 5 cause the other zoom levels aren't really needed.I have tried everything to set the tiles to cache on the fly. Is it not suppose to go in the same folder as the tiles that is seeded?

Comment: You have "Enable direct integration with GeoServer WMS" checked from Caching defaults?

Comment: yes I do. I also have Automatically configure a geowebcache layer for each new layer or layer group.The grid set all to ESPG 3857

Comment: If you have your own client try to use WMS from direct gwc address and check if it is changing anything: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms? I believe there is something wrong with the layer preview and accessing tiles through geoserver/wms or geoserver/workspace/wms.

Comment: All right, the layer preview app does not trigger seeding but the this one does http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/demo/topp:states?gridSet=EPSG:4326&format=image/png

Comment: Could that also be the reason why I get a 400 error when I try to send the bounding box to seed the layers.
My wms that is on the openlayers page for the map is 192.168.50.1:8080/geoserver/test/gwc/service/wms.

Comment: Seed link from "Tile Layers" goes to /geoserver/gwc/ and seeding the automatically cached layer topp:states with BBOX and layers 00-08 works for me without errors.

Comment: When I go to that specific link it just says its not available but when I go to 192.168.50.1:8080/geoserver/gwc then I get the geoWebcache page. Other wise if I try go to that specific link but using my 192.168.50.1:8080/geoserver/gwc/demo/test:base/gridSet=test_EPSG:3857&format=image/png which gives me a http 400 bad request error

Comment: You have made your own gridset "test_EPSG:3857"?

Comment: Yes as there was no grid set for EPSG:3857 so I had to create my own one. Instead of using the EPSG:900913. I was not 100% sure to use the 4326. As I manilly wanted to use the created 3857 as my postgreSQL database my geometrys are 3857 so it would not casue me to have to reproject the native SRS or the Declared SRS I wouldn't have to force the one or reproject rather keeping it that was in the SRS selection

Comment: I recommend to forward one step at a time. Use the demo layers with default gridsets. Change into your own data and default gridsets. Test demo data with your gridset and finally your own data with your gridset. I am not sure is IP 192.168.50.1:8080 adds some proxy settings to the view. Unfortunately I do not use integrated GWC myself and I fear I can't guide you farther than this.

Comment: ok thanks anyway. Will try those out and see what it will do.